# How to have the contract check if the msg.sender currently owns a specific token. (erc721)

Tags: tokens, erc-721, balances, nft, erc-1155

Assuming I have a contract to mint my own NFTs: (I'm thinking ERC-721, but not necessarily).

I want to create another smart contract that before doing anything, verifies that the address interacting with it (`msg.sender`) currently owns an NFT minted by that specific contract. Even better, if it could read an attribute, like the NFT id.

Is that even possible? I did some research on it, but apparently the address doesn't actually stores the balances/tokens, only eth. But I'm guessing it must be a way, given how those NFTs gallery works.
If it's possible, how could I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If contracts is an ERC721 then you can query how many tokens a user owns with `balanceOf`

```
uint count = token.balanceOf(user);
if (count > 0) {
    // User owns at least 1 index
}
```

If the tokens implements the optional `ERC721Enumerable` interface you can use `tokenOfOwnerByIndex` to retrieve the tokenId of owned tokens by a user.

```
try token.tokenOfOwnerByIndex(user, 0) returns (uint tokenId) {
    // First token owned by user
} catch (bytes memory) {
    // No tokens owned by user
}
```

For other details see the [EIP 721](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721), or [EIP 1155](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1155).

Comment: Thanks Ismael, do you mind a follow up? How is `token` defined in your example? Since this is another contract, Does it need to be the one who deploys the ERC712 contract or is there someway to interface with it?

Comment: @Justcurious Something like `IERC721Enumerable token = IERC721Enumerable(0x12341234...)` should work if the token supports IERC721Enumerable.